# How to stop W3 Total Cache from globally replacing URLs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, w3-total-cache

I'm trying to create a custom `wp_head` implementation in a Wordpress theme to work alongside the original method.

I've setup my code like this in `functions.php`:

```
function wp_head_r()
{
    echo '<script src="http://sample-url.com/js/file.js"></script>';
}
```

Then in header.php, I have this:

```
wp_head();     //original
wp_head_r();
```

The problem I have is that the Wordpress install I'm working with has W3 Total Cache installed. So what is happening is that any file that has `sample-url.com` that references a JavaScript or CSS file is being replaced to `sample-url-cdn.com` before it is output to the page.

This was happening with enqueued scripts and stylesheets, and I was thinking that setting up a custom `wp_head` method would prevent this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it possible to create some kind of filter to prevent W3 Total Cache from globally replacing all the urls?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. The trick is to use a filter with a high priority, effectively overriding [I think] the one that W3 Total Cache is leveraging.

Here's the code [for functions.php]:

```
function my_filter_w3tc_cdn_url( $new_url, $url, $is_engine_mirror )
{
    if(preg_match('/\/(my_special_dir_pattern)/i', $new_url))
    {
        $new_url = $url;
    }

    return $new_url;
};

add_filter( 'w3tc_cdn_url', 'my_filter_w3tc_cdn_url', 100, 3 );
```

I used `preg_match` to target all urls that fit a specific pattern, and then exclude them from being updated to the CDN url. Also, notice that I used a priority of 100, which seems high enough and worked in my specific use case.

Hope it helps.